# Create Alert when someone hit salesforce restapi or site and create lead

Tags: trigger, api, notification, alert

i need a alert notification in salesforce at the moment to user who is logged in, when someone hit our api or create a record through that api. 
i have used this vf page in my site and want when a lead is created a popup notification apear on salesforc e window. on whichever page a user is.

visualforce

```
 <apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" action="{!createleadext}" controller="newleadext">
    <script>
    alert("{!leadid}");
    </script>

    </apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public with sharing class newleadext {

public string tonumber{get;set;}
public string Fromnumber{get;set;}
public string CallerName{get;set;}
public string callSid{get;set;}
public string Direction{get;set;}
public string Callstatus{get;set;}
public string leadid{get;set;}

public List<Lead> lead_insert{get;set;}

public void createleadext()
{
   tonumber=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('tonumber');
   Fromnumber=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Fromnumber');
   CallerName=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('CallerName');
   callSid=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('callSid');
   Direction=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Direction');
    Callstatus=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Callstatus');


   lead_insert= new List<Lead>(); 
   Lead ld= new Lead();
   ld.LastName=CallerName;
   ld.company='Didforsale';
   lead_insert.add(ld);
   insert lead_insert; 
   leadid=lead_insert[0].id;
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the provided description the ask isn't quite clear, but it sounds like you want to send an alert to users once a lead has been created via a VF page.

If this is correct then you could most likely utilize something like one of the JavaScript components for VisualForce like the [Providing Status for Asynchronous Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_ajax_async_status.htm).

If you're actually looking to throw up an alert to the user on successful lead creation you could also look into JavaScript Remoting. You would just want to annotate the controller method with @RemoteAction and have the alert() call present in the callback function.

There a great [example of JS Remoting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm) that covers this in current Documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the reference but do they work when lead will created by api hit, like someone hit our site url and lead will be created from there.

Comment: I think you might also be confusing an `<apex:page>` action method with a custom REST endpoint. Your above code shows the utilization of a page action method, in which cases a user needs to request the page, and the action function fires when the server receives the request. In this case the user would be able to be notified with the JavaScript alert. If instead you're looking to create a custom REST endpoint, then the JavaScript wouldn't even be a part of the picture as the endpoint would just receive the input directly to create the lead.